# How to create a new column in SELECT CASE when string contains Arabic words?

Tags: sql-server, collation, case, encoding, unicode

I have a problem with a select case when statement, I would like to add a new column in the select case when statement, I got the result but with `?????` because I have set the column to Arabic words, I have tried to convert the content of the new column to `nvarchar(55)` unfortunately, I got the same result.

How can I get the correct result?

```
SELECT case when ( CAST(o.startTime as time(7)) > cast(Start as time(7))) 
          then  cast('قدوم' as nvarchar(55))
          else cast('رجوع' as nvarchar(55)) end as stat,
       userId, FirstName
from   Users, TimeTable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case because you're using an `NVARCHAR` data type in your cast which supports the entire **Unicode** character set, all you're missing from your ad-hoc string's prefix is `N` character to signify to SQL Server to treat the string as `NVARCHAR`, at which point makes your `CAST()` function call redundant and not needed either. E.g. `SELECT N'Some Text'` will produce an `NVARCHAR` string as opposed to just `SELECT 'Some Text'` which produces a `VARCHAR` string.

Solomon Rutzky's answer provides a clear-cut example of this as well, with more insightful information.

---

For anyone who runs into this issue while using `VARCHAR` (or similar) data types, the below *are the droids you're looking for*:

You need to use an Arabic character supporting collation in the column, for the table, in the database, or at the server instance level such as `Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS`.

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561385/5059085) has good information on it.

For ad-hoc queries and values you should be able to use the [`COLLATE` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15) as needed. For example with your above query if we needed to use `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT
    case 
        when (CAST(o.startTime as time(7)) > cast(Start as time(7))) then  cast(N'قدوم' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS as varchar(55)) 
        else cast(N'رجوع' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS as varchar(55)) end as stat,
    userId, 
    FirstName 
from Users,TimeTable
```

Comment: Hi there. When working with `NVARCHAR` data, the collation is entirely irrelevant to determining which characters can be stored: it's all of them as it's Unicode. Neither the `COLLATE` clause, nor even the `CAST`, are necessary here. The only relevant change you made to the O.P.'s code is adding the `N` prefix on the string literals. I explain more in [my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/290354/30859).

Comment: Hi JD didn’t I write a comment saying you needed an N’ about 6 hours ago ? It seems to have disappeared

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64 Yes and actually I replied with a comment thanking you for the reminder lol. I'm guessing a mod cleaned up the comments and likely will happen again for your last comment and this one too. 

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Ah yes you're right. I'm noobing it up all over here since it's not often I need to work with the `NVARCHAR` data type, surprisingly. I've corrected my answer, and you have my upvotes for your in depth and helpful answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: Still wrong, just remove cast and collate, you only need `N''`

Comment: @Charlieface I think you might've read through my update a little quick. I did remove the `CAST()` and `COLLATE` functions from my answer to OP's question. I also updated my original answer for a separate case where if you wanted to cast the result to a `VARCHAR` data type, as it might be helpful for someone who stumbles on this with a tangentially related question.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using Unicode / UTF-16 (i.e. `NVARCHAR`), you do not *need* either the `CAST` or even an `Arabic_*` collation. The only *requirement* for string literals is to prefix them with a capital-"N":

```sql
SELECT 'قدوم' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS, '-o-' AS [-o-], 'رجوع' COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS;
-- ???? -o- ????

SELECT N'قدوم' COLLATE French_CI_AS, '-o-' AS [-o-], N'رجوع' COLLATE French_CI_AS;
-- قدوم -o- رجوع
```

<sup>(the `-o-` field is used as a separator to prevent the Bi-Direction formatting, inherent with Arabic and Hebrew code points, from displaying the second column on the left in the T-SQL comment below the query when rendered in HTML)</sup>

When using `NVARCHAR` (including `NCHAR` and the should-never-be-used `NTEXT`), the encoding is always UTF-16, hence the character set never changes (it's always Unicode, which is a single character set). In this case, the collation mainly affects sorting and comparisons (which are not being done here).

If you were using `VARCHAR`, then an Arabic collation would be needed in order to set the code page in order to support the Arabic characters (Windows Code Page 1256).

The reason why your initial `'قدوم'` returned `????` is that the string literal was not prefixed with `N`, making it a `VARCHAR` string, in which case it was converted to the code page associated with the default collation of the current database you were using, which clearly was *not* an Arabic collation. This conversion happens as the query is initially parsed, which means that your string was already `????` *before* the cast operation converted it to `NVARCHAR`. If you had been using a database that had an Arabic default collation, then your string literal would have worked even without the `N` prefix, and the `CAST` to `NVARCHAR` would have been just as unnecessary.

For more information on working with strings / encodings / Unicode / collations, please visit my site: [Collations Info](https://collations.info/)

---

P.S. I would recommend that you not be doing old-style JOINs such as `FROM TableA, TableB WHERE TableA.JoinColumn = TableB.JoinColumn`. While that syntax has not been deprecated, the related outer join syntax — `*=` and `=*` — was actually [removed in SQL Server 2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms144262(v=sql.90)). So, for consistency (and personally, I would also throw in readability), you should instead use the `INNER JOIN` clause. Also, it's always best to prefix object names with their Schema name. The end result is:

```sql
FROM dbo.TableA
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB
        ON TableB.JoinColumn = TableA.JoinColumn
```

Comment: +1 for the answer but a minor correction needed: old style comma join has not and will likely never be deprecated as it is standard SQL. What has been deprecated are the non-standard old style outer joins (`*=` and `=*`).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks for pointing that out. I misremembered and was being lazy when I found the documentation referring to the removal of `*=` and `=*` and didn't check the current documentation to see if there was a deprecation notice of the basic `INNER` / `CROSS` join syntax. I have updated my answer accordingly, and this time included the link to the documentation.